# Does Realm for React Native protect against injection attacks?

Tags: react-native, realm

A python library for SQL that I've used provided sanitation of query parameters to protect against injection attacks if you used the `('query == $0', param)` approach, but not if you created the string yourself, i.e. `('query == param')`. Is this the same in Realm for React Native?

Is there any functional difference between `` results.filtered(`query == ${param}`) `` and `results.filtered('query == $0', param)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, those are different, and `filtered('query == $0', param)` will work regardless of the contents of `param`, while `` filtered(`query == ${param}`) `` will not.

The substitution parameter syntax does not sanitize the input *per se*. The interface for the low-level query engine isn't string-based, so unlike with an SQL library there never is a query string with the parameters substituted in involved at all, so there isn't actually any sanitization needed. The end result is largely the same, though.

Comment: Thanks! Work regardless of the param...What param's would work on the $0 way that wouldn't work in the ${} way?